# Joomla Super Admin Password Change

Tags: joomla

I have been trying to change my super admin password on my database through the phpmyadmin on MAMP (localhost), I have coded the password in MD5 format and even got the confirmation message. However that does not solve my problem, I am still unable to log in in the joomla administration panel - Password and Username doesn't match error.

Whats surprising is that even with the confirmation message, the phpmyadmin screen doesn't record the last reset time.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or any field that I should complete?

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F#Change_the_Password_in_the_Database

Comment: Are you sure the password is supposed stored as a straight md5 hash?

Comment: This really depends on version.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to create a new normal user and either make it the root user in your configuration.php or go into phpmyadmin and then add the new user to the super admin group.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute the following query (changing "jos31" with your database prefix):

```
INSERT INTO `jos31_users`
   (`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`)
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2',
    '433903e0a9d6a712e00251e44d29bf87:UJ0b9J5fufL3FKfCc0TLsYJBh2PFULvT', '');
INSERT INTO `jos31_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8');
```

you could after login as: admin2 / admin

Another way is just paste the folowing password to your current super admin user and your new password will be: admin

> 433903e0a9d6a712e00251e44d29bf87:UJ0b9J5fufL3FKfCc0TLsYJBh2PFULvT

[here is the complete tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F)

Answer (score 0):

The one with 'secret' and 'admin' is found all around Internet. But there may be a situation when your Joomla site for some reason cannot change password in a normal way, and you don't want to go with "secret". Then there is another solution that's quite obvious, though maybe not for everyone...

1. You install Joomla 3* or whatever version you need (along with all its dependencies) ON YOUR LOCAL COMPUTER. During the setup you create your admin user/password. Now this is the password you want to use in your site where you've lost your Super User access. You just need to insert the HASH of that password into your site's MySQL db. So let's get that one now.
2. You go terminal/console, log in to mysql:

   ```
   $mysql -u root -p
   ```

   type in your password you've set up during the mysql installation.
3. Use your database name and db table prefix from your configuration.php in the root of your Joomla installation. Or you may remember them from your setup. 
   Then you derive your Super User password HASH from the db using this commands:

   ```
   $mysql>USE $your_database_name;
   $mysql>SELECT password from ${table_prefix}_users where name='Super User';
   ```

Now suppose your db name is "joomla" and your db_table prefix is "jehn34_".
Then your command will look like (don't forget the ";" at the end of each command!!!):

```
USE joomla;

SELECT password from jehn34_users where name='Super User';
```

You'll get your output like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| password                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| $OhMyGOODNESShereis02935468567$%^&*yourhashedpas0239u8i0e0jh |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You know your password for this one, so now you can now insert the string above into your MySQL Admin of your web-site in the corresponding field. Then you can use that password of yours.